# Let's have some celebrations for International Programmers' Day/Night

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Last year I didn't recall seeing any celebrations on SO for [Programmers' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmers'_Day). Was that just an "odd" year, or is it just something that isn't celebrated here?

Also, if there isn't any particular reason for not celebrating, could we maybe have a few banners up or something to commemorate the day?

Comment: Every day is Programmer's Day.

Comment: ...and yet we celebrate April Fools.  How sad.

Comment: I liked the question cheers

Comment: Never heard of it either. How exactly is one supposed to celebrate this day?

Comment: @MartinSmith, by posting quality posts on SO :)

Comment: @MartinSmith by drinking a lot of coffee beer, then doing some code golfing while drunk, for kicks.

Comment: @MartinSmith wear your best shirt http://imgkk.com/i/9xx7.png

Comment: @AmitJoki You are already celebrating it, I see. :))

Comment: Wouldn't Programmer's Night be more appropriate?

Comment: @iCodez isn't it the same thing?

Answer (score 38):

Never knew this existed! Of course every day is our day as Robert Harvey commented.

Yes, we must definitely celebrate it because, when we can celebrate April Fools day springing up some unicorns and making a fool out of ourselves to break rocks by hammering on our mouse in a programming site, then it makes ***perfect*** sense to celebrate the day for us `:)`

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, due to Java, it happens on day -125 of the year. That makes it a bit hard to commemorate.